# What is call by object in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I come from c/c++ background. I am very much familiar with call by value/reference.Here I am not understanding what is meant by call by object.Does it mean passing the object itself?

Comment: http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm

Comment: Much like passing a pointer (by value) in C. If you modify the object, you will change the object that exists outside the function. But if you reassign the variable, it will not affect the variable outside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/) explains it in detail.
A function receives a reference to (and will access) the same object in memory as used by the caller. However, it does not receive the box that the caller is storing this object in; as in pass-by-value, the function provides its own box and creates a new variable for itself